# Cross-Validation Performance Aggregation with Undefined Values

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I wonder what is the correct way to calculate average performance over several folds in cross-validation.

For example, I have 5 folds of F1 with values

`[0.5 0.3 0.25 null 0.7]`

What's is the average F1 of this system?

- I could take null as 0 or just output null as an average result.
- Alternatively, I can take only defined four values and divide by 4, but this is not correct either, because if there is some system that did 0.1 on this fold, it's performance will be poorer that the one with null, however, 0.1 is much better that null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the context. (In the following I'm including references to `numpy` just for future references for those using it.)

- If the `null` occurred because the cv-fold was somehow undefined for the problem, then you could ignore it (e.g., by calling [`np.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html). Presumably, for "real life", you just wouldn't have a dataset equivalent to such a fold.
- If the `null` occurred because the predictor utterly failed for this fold, then the result could either be (it's a matter of *your* interpretation):

  - `nan`, because the overall predictor behavior is undefined (in this case, you might just use [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)).
  - The average with the worst case possible (indeed 0 for the [f1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)), if you'd spot for a given set that it's malfunctioning, and output just some arbitrary result (in this case, you might use [`np.nan_to_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)).

---

*By far, the best thing you could do* is figure out the reason for this value, and then eliminate it. This should ideally just never happen, and probably should be considered a bug; before solving the bug, just consider your estimator unsuitable for performance estimation.